# Trying to determine if a specific behavior is allowed in wxPython text

Tags: python, xml, text, wxwidgets

I am trying to determine if something is possible. I haven't written any code for this specifically yet.

Using wxPython I would like to set up a text box (possibly a staticText) with primarily un-editable text. However I need certain parts, individual words, to be editable similar to PDF document with added text boxes.

The ultimate goal is to visually display an XML file and allow a user to directly edit only element text and nothing else in-situ. I have a couple of other ways of doing this but they are very much sub-optimal.

Thanks for any input/direction/help.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice idea, but wx' text boxes are either entirely read only, or editable.

I think the way to go for it is to query your position inside the text box for each cursor movement, and toggle the text box state readonly/editable according to you current position, current selection, etc..

It looks like a tough task, though... :-)

Comment: Well, like you said, it's a nice idea. If I wasn't on a time schedule I would look into how to extend the functionality of wx' text boxes. Maybe later on...

Thanks!